# PHP: $_POST["startId$i"]) != ""

Tags: php, forms

I am trying to process a form that is dynamically created and therefore varies in length.  The while loop seems to work fine.  However, the 'if' statement is not; it should only print the startId$i and corId$i *if and only if* the form's particular text field was filled in.  The code is printing a line for every text field on the form, regardless of if it was left empty or not.

```
$i = 0;
while(!is_null($_POST["startId$i"])){                                                       
    if(($_POST["startId$i"]) != ""){
        echo "startId: " . $_POST["startId$i"] . " ---<br>";
        echo "corId: " . $_POST["corId$i"] . " ---<br>";

    }
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: I tried if(!empty($_POST["startId$i"])) { ... but still, it did not work.  Here< I copied an pasted directly from a 'view source' example in the  form page: <input type="hidden" name="startId3" value="94">

Comment: Try to use my solution from the second code block.

Comment: Use `!isset`, not `!is_null`. I can't really see why the `if` would be breaking, though. Any particular reason you're not using pseudo-arrays for input names?

Comment: I just slapped myself in the head. I was checking the wrong form input... one is always set and one is sometimes blank!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$i = 0;
while(isset($_POST["startId$i"])){                                                       
    if( !empty($_POST["startId$i"]) ){
        echo "startId: " . $_POST["startId$i"] . " ---<br>";
        echo "corId: " . $_POST["corId$i"] . " ---<br>";

    }
    $i++;
}
```

Can you manage with fields names ?

If yes, better way is to name inputs with `name="startId[0]"` and `name="corId[0]"` and so on...

Then in PHP you just do:

```
$startIds = $_POST['startId'];
$corIds   = $_POST['corId'];

foreach ( $startIds as $k => $startId ) {
    if ( !empty($startId) ) {
        $corId = $corIds[$k];
        echo "startId: " . $startId . " ---<br>";
        echo "corId: " . $corId . " ---<br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: isset and !empty are redundant. !empty does suffice (it won't throw notices)

Comment: !empty will check if key is set and value is not empty.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `empty()` in this case:

```
if(!empty($_POST["startId$i"])) {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to check the real content of $_POST. You can do that via `var_dump($_POST);`

You may find out, for example, that the empty fields contain whitespaces. In that case the [trim()](http://php.net/trim) function may help.

For example:

```
while(isset($_POST["startId$i"])){                                                       
    if(trim($_POST["startId$i"])){
        echo "startId: " . $_POST["startId$i"] . " ---<br>";
        echo "corId: " . $_POST["corId$i"] . " ---<br>";
    }
    $i++;
}
```